# Image comments in Java

Tags: java, comments, image

I need to make a java program which takes a directory of images and displays them one at a time - Fair enough. However, alongside this picture viewer I need a text box in which the user may comment about this individual picture. This should then be saved to the image so that if I ended execution and re-run the program loading the same directory again the comment attached to the specific image remains. Similarly if I move on to a different picture and come back the comment remains.

I know this can be achieved in multiple ways but im not sure how to best approach it.

Does anyone have an advice for me? All help is greatly appreciated

Thanks :)

Comment: You generally don't store comments *inside* the image.  You should save it externally, possibly in a file you modify in the directory itself, like windows does with `desktop.ini`.  Myself, I'd probably use a database.

Comment: Would an xml saving the image name and then the comments be a good choice?? Thankyou greatly :)

Comment: If you mean just a single XML file, there's no clear benefit to this over having an `SQLite` database. In fact, there's probably downsides.

Comment: Packages like `javax.imageio` allow you to deal with the metadata stored in images. Some image formats don't allow you to add arbitrary comments, though. It's probably not what you want to do if this is something like an image gallery with a commenting system.

Comment: This was what I was originally thinking Jon. The images I will be working with will be of a defined JPEG format throughout. Would this be an easier way to do it do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) ?  This works with TIFF, JPEG, PNG and other common image formats. It looks a better fit to your requirements than dealing with XML files containing the  image metadata.